# Magento category page displays no products

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento-1.5

When I view a category page (ie. url.com/category.html) the page shows the category title, description but no products. Doesn't seem to be loading them since I get this message "There are no products matching the selection."

The products are enabled, visible in catalog & search, have quantity and are in stock and product categories are listed under a root category called "Default Category". I have a featured products listed on the home page by category ID which display fine and individual product detail pages display as they should as well.

I have tried refreshing cache/indexes and searching Google all to no avail. I thought it may be an issue caused by a customization I made to the theme but switching to the default theme made no change so it would seem I must be missing something in the product or category configurations.

Possibly related? – searching always returns no results even if by product name

I am using magento ver 1.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many attributes do you have?  Too many attributes marked as "Visible on product listing page" can break the indexes.  Are there records in the catalog_product_flat_* table(s)?

Comment: I haven't added any additional attributes so there are just the defaults, doesn't look like any are set to Visible. I'm not sure how to check the records of the table, would that be through PHP MyAdmin? If so I don't currently have access to that but can get it later on today

Comment: Edit: I believe there are 39 attributes

Comment: Yes, phpMyAdmin would give you access to the database.

Comment: Yes, there are three records in catalog_product_flat_1 corresponding to the three test products I have added

Answer (score 6):

Please check following settings are done for your product

1. The products must be Visible in Catalog.
2. The products must be Enabled.
3. Product must have a stock Quantity.
4. The product must be set to In Stock.
5. If the product is set not to track stock, it still need to have a stock Quantity and be set to In Stock.
6. The product must be assigned to the target Category.
7. If using multi-website mode (or if you imported the products through Data Flow), the products must be assigned to the target Website.
8. You must refresh your “var/Cache” & rebuild all indexes from admin > system > index management

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Next time if you have same problem you can try two things:

**1 - Reindex catalog and products**

**2 - Check user permissions**
If you move your database from one server to another or you restore the database you might want to check the `customer_group` table. More specifically you should check the **"NOT LOGGED IN"** records and its ID, it should be "0" if it is not the products won't be visible for that group of users which is pretty much all users on most Magento shops.

Answer (score 0):

OK after I looked up the records and replaced my theme's list.phtml file with the default one (for about the 100th time) products started displaying. Not sure what changed but as long as they continue to display I'm happy.